Modify json based on condition with jolt
I am given the below json and it needs to be concatenated based on condition if it not null
{
  "id": "4583",
  "price": "149.99",
  "sale_price": ""
}

Can someone help me out here?
expected output
{
  "id": "4583",
  "price": "149.99 EUR",
  "sale_price": ""
}

In above json price was concatenated with EUR but sale_price is as it is because it is null.
I am using below jolt, it us updating sale_price as well.
{
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "price": "=concat(@(1,price),' EUR')",
      "sale_price": ["=isNull", "=concat(@(1,sale_price),' EUR')"]
    }
  }


I hope the following Jolt solution will be helpful to you.
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "price": "=concat(@(1,price),' EUR')",
      "sale_amount": "=concat(@(1,sale_price),' EUR')"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "sale_price": {
        "": {
          "@1": "sale_price"
        },
        "*": {
          "@(2,sale_amount)": "sale_price"
        }
      },
      "*": "&"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "sale_amount": ""
    }
  }
]


The empty value("") and the null value are different. So, we need to manipulate an empty value in order to convert to a null one, and consequently to be able to apply the isNull and the notNull functions such as
[
  {//convert the empty values to `null` ones
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "": { "@": "&2" },
        "*": { "@1": "&2" }
      }
    }
  },
  {//apply isNull and notNull functions consequtively
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*rice": ["=isNull", "=concat(@(1,&),' EUR')"]
      //Elvis Operator returns RHS(right-hand-side) whenever LHS is not null
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*rice": ["=notNull", ""]
      //Elvis Operator returns RHS whenever LHS is null
    }
  }
]


this link + (4 times) PgDn  ->> Elvis
Operator

